# How can I convert a varchar to a datetime format of hh:mm:ss?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following results returned from a query:

```
2030
1200
1400
1545
```

Is there a way to convert these to times in the format hh:mm:ss in SQL (SQL Server)?

For example, the above entries would be converted as follows:

```
2030 = 20:30:00
1200 = 12:00:00
1400 = 14:00:00
1545 = 15:45:00
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `stuff()` :

```
select cast(stuff(2030, 3, 0, ':') as time(0))
```

If your query returning string numbers then you can use :

```
. . .
where charindex ('.', n) = 0;
```

Comment: This seems to do what I need it to do. How can I make sure that there are no decimal places?

Comment: You should stop dealing with date values as strings. You can format this in the front end and keep the datatype as a date.

Comment: I agree, but I am not in charge of the front end. I work with the data that comes to me.

Comment: what is an example of a decimal place you might receive?  What would 2030.66 mean for example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You are querying this, send the data as a time. But if you are truly stuck then just look at the syntax for either CONVERT or FORMAT (if you are on 2012 or greater).

Comment: @Cato they are referring to the default display format for a time datatype which contains .000 for the milliseconds.

Comment: @ic3man7019 use `time(0)` instead. Just using `time` defaults the datatype to `time(7)`.

Comment: @Larnu. . . Seems issue was in `time(0)` instead `time`. If so, then thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToTime(@myInput nvarchar(4))  
RETURNS nvarchar(7)
AS   
-- Returns the input as valid time string 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret nvarchar(7);              
        SET @ret = SUBSTRING(@myInput,1,2)+':'+ SUBSTRING(@myInput,3,2)+':00'
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

And call like:

```
SELECT ToTime(2030);
SELECT ToTime(1200);
...
```

Comment: This works but scalar functions are so terrible for performance. And in this case is way overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FORMAT`:

```
select format(2030 * 100,'##:##:##')
```

More info about `FORMAT` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).